# How to select all inputs having same name insert into Mysql?

Tags: java, html, mysql, hibernate, jsp

How the form mutiple input having same name insert into Mysql ?? I've tried insert three same name select option into  Mysql ,but when submit just all become into one column，every questionid has it own score ，for example,I have three questionid column in mysql and each column has it own score,so it  might have three score column for each questionid  just like this---->[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAQgw.jpg) and I have a problem like this ----->[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCqKb.jpg)!!

jsp code:

```
 <form id="result" role="form" class="form-inline" action="mature.htm" method="post">

 <select name="score" class="form-control input-lg">
                       <font>
                                <option value="1">○</option>
                                <option value="2">△</option>
                                <option value="3">×</option></select>
                        </font>
                <font size="5"><select name="score" class="form-control input-lg">
                                <option value="1">○</option>
                                <option value="2">△</option>
                                <option value="3">×</option></select>
                        </font>
                <font size="5"><select name="score" class="form-control input-lg">
                                <option value="1">○</option>
                                <option value="2">△</option>
                                <option value="3">×</option></select>
                        </font>
```

entity model:Result.java

```
 @Column(name="score", length=45)
public String getScore() {
    return this.score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}
```

This is my hibernate (create)DEO:

```
 public void create2(Result e,Result e2)
{

    try{
         Session s=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
         s.beginTransaction();
         e.setQuestionid("lokesh@mail.com");   
         s.save(e);
         s.getTransaction().commit();
         Session s2=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
         s2.beginTransaction();
         e2.setQuestionid("l.com");   
         s2.save(e2);
         s2.getTransaction().commit();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: font tag is depreciated

Comment: sorry,I just missed it!!

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is your first select tag should be either inside or outside the font tag as you are closing it wrong way. Secondly it is a bad practice to store whole HTML in database as it consumes much more space than saving only key and values if possible.
In my case I have saved like this:

```
{"q":[{"qid":"Do you solve the issue?","answer":{"1":"yes"}},{"qid":"what was the issue?","answer":["credit card problem"]}]}
```

I retrieve the above mention json from the html similar to this:

```
<label id="lbl1">do you solve the issue?</label>
<input type="radio" name="qid1" value="yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="qid1" value="no">No<br>

<label id="lbl1">what was the issue?</label>
<select id="qid1">
    <option value="1">credit card problem</option>
    <option value="2">dedit card problem</option>
</select>
```

as you can see first question is saving only one answer and second question is saving array which can save multiple answer of select tag.

Saving 5 select tag to html per user would take 100 times more space than Json. As per my calculation I had saved about 1 million record which took about 1 Gb space